# Is there any reason why foldr type signature differs from foldl one?

Tags: haskell, fold

I'm a little confused in how foldl defined comparing to foldr. Foldr differs from foldl not only in associativity, but also in folding function argument order:

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

I don't see any reasons why foldl couldn't be defined like that:

```
foldl :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldl f acc [] = acc
foldl f acc (x:xs) = foldl f (f x acc) xs
```

So foldl can be appliend to non-commutative folding functions as well as 
foldr:

```
Prelude> foldr (:) [] [1..5]
[1,2,3,4,5]
Prelude> foldl (:) [] [1..5]
<interactive>:4:7: error:
<...>
Prelude> myfoldl (:) [] [1..5]
[5,4,3,2,1]
```

With standard foldl definition we need use `flip` to get same behavior as with `foldr`

Comment: The "flipping" of the arguments is actually logical: you can see it as a "hint" to how the folding happens.

Comment: Plus, you get an error if you use the wrong version accidentally.

Answer (score 7):

You get the following nice equational properties with that order:

```
foldl (+) z [a, b, c] = (((z + a) + b) + c)
foldr (+) z [a, b, c] = a + (b + (c + z))
```

Comment: Doesn't look different to me: `myfoldl (+) z [a, b, c] = (c + (b + (a + z)))`

Comment: @aryndin that's not either of the things listed in the post. It might look like it because `(+)` is commutative, but most operations are not.

Comment: you need to remember to reverse the list though, it's just one bit of knowledge but still one more than the status quo.